# How to perform arithmetic operations separately for each group and average the results in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Here example of mydata

```
mydat=structure(list(MDM_Key = c(26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 55L, 
55L, 55L, 55L, 55L), SalePrice = c(91.51, 91.51, 0, 91.51, 91.51, 
0, 3344.44, 0, 2721.35, 3200, 0), ActionDuration = c(20L, 40L, 
500L, 37L, 30L, 400L, 155L, 1074L, 5L, 61L, 350L), Articul = c("LLE-A60-11-230-40-E27", 
"LLE-A60-11-230-40-E27", "BC1-C5E04-111", "LLE-A60-11-230-40-E27", 
"LLE-A60-11-230-40-E27", "BC1-C5E04-111", "LPDO401-100-K03", 
"LPDO401-100-K03", "LPDO401-100-K03", "LPDO401-100-K03", "LPDO401-100-K03"
), maxPrice = c(101.68, 101.68, 5351.15, 101.68, 101.68, 5351.15, 
4838.66, 3650, 3650, 5037.73, 5037.73), minPrice = c(101.68, 
101.68, 5351.15, 101.68, 101.68, 5351.15, 2993.49, 2993.49, 3650, 
5037.73, 3400), avgPrice = c(101.68, 101.68, 5351.15, 101.68, 
101.68, 5351.15, 4628.3121, 3608.1565, 3650, 5037.73, 4238.4785
), QtySale = c(3456L, 54634L, 63855L, 181089L, 216786L, 100L, 
3582L, 67263L, 582L, 601L, 3007L), QtySale6mAfterAction = c(0L, 
0L, 2000L, 0L, 0L, 1000L, 0L, 9966L, 0L, 0L, 1457L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

I need to perform a series of arithmetic operations for each MDM_Key.

1. divide `QtySale/ActionDuration` before the row where salesPrice=0.
   Let's consider `MDM_Key=26`
   for example the first row

   3456/20=172.8

second row

```
54634/40=1365.85
```

Next comes the row where SalesPrice=0, there is no need to divide anything.

after this row with zero there is data again
they also need to be divided

```
181089/37=4894.29
216786/30=7226.2
```

after that, the obtained values must be averaged

```
per_day_before_zero=(172.8+1365.85+4894.29+7226.2)/4=3414.785
```

Now for this MDM Key we can go back to the rows where salesprice=0 , there are 2 of them in this example for MDM_Key=26.
However, we always divide their values by `180` and work with the `QtySale6mAfterAction` column,
in other words, for such rows `QtySale6mAfterAction/180`.
that is,

```
2000/180=11.11
1000/400=2.5
```

and also `averaging per_day_in_zero=(11.11+2.5)/2=6.8`

After this, a similar procedure is necessary for the next MDM_Key

Thus the desired output

```
MDM_key per_day_before_zero per_day_in_zero
26        3414.785                 6.8
55        49.78 3                  1.73
```

How can i do it?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to take a look into e.g. [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.hadley.nz/). After reading the first few chapters your problem should be easy to solve. However, here's a possible way:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- mydat %>% 
  filter(SalePrice != 0) %>% 
  mutate(div_val = QtySale/ActionDuration) %>% 
  group_by(MDM_Key) %>%
  summarize(per_day_before_zero = mean(div_val))

df2 <- mydat %>% 
  filter(SalePrice == 0) %>% 
  mutate(div_val = QtySale6mAfterAction/180) %>% 
  group_by(MDM_Key) %>%
  summarize(per_day_in_zero = mean(div_val))

df1 %>% left_join(df2, join_by(MDM_Key))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `{dplyr}` solution wrapped in one piped statement:

```
library(dplyr)
mydat |>
  mutate(newvar = ifelse(SalePrice != 0, QtySale / ActionDuration, NA), 
         per_day_before_zero = mean(newvar, na.rm = TRUE), 
         newvar2 = ifelse(SalePrice == 0, QtySale6mAfterAction / 180L, NA),
         per_day_in_zero = mean(newvar2, na.rm = TRUE), 
         .by = MDM_Key) |>
  filter(SalePrice == 0) |>
  select(MDM_Key, per_day_before_zero, per_day_in_zero) |>
  unique()
```

gives

```
>  MDM_Key per_day_before_zero per_day_in_zero
> 1      26          3414.78682        8.333333
> 3      55            49.78738       31.730556
```

Note, I assume you want to divide by the constant `180L`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option with `data.table`:

```
dt <- as.data.table(mydat)

x <-
  dt[, c("per_day_before_zero", "per_day_in_zero") := list(mean(ifelse(SalePrice !=
                                                                         0, QtySale / ActionDuration, NA), na.rm = T),
                                                           mean(ifelse(
                                                             SalePrice == 0, QtySale6mAfterAction / 180, NA
                                                           ), na.rm = T)), by = MDM_Key ]
res <-
  unique(x[, c("MDM_Key", "per_day_before_zero", "per_day_in_zero")])
```